# HTML td will not break to new line with <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table, doctype

I am having an issue with getting table cell to respond to styles as expected.  Please do not recommend using div and CSS.  I know it is better, but not appropriate for this particular issue.  I also cannot change the doctype because it is CMS with closed source.  This works as expected with the XHTML doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.foottable{
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.foottable td{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>                  
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="foottable">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>
                <b>About</b>
                <a href="info.html">About</a>
                <a href="press.html">Press</a>
                <a target="_blank" href="http://blog.com/">Blog</a>
                <a href="events.html">Events</a>
                <a href="stores.html">Store Locations</a>
                <a href="ind.html">Site Map</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Customer Service</b>
                <a href="shipping.html">Shipping</a>
                <a href="returnpolicy.html">Returns</a>
                <a href="giftcert.html">Gift Certificates</a>
                <a href="privacypolicy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
                <a href="terms.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as the doctype is HTML 4.01 it does not work as expected

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.foottable{
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.foottable td{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>                  
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="foottable">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>
                <b>About</b>
                <a href="info.html">About</a>
                <a href="press.html">Press</a>
                <a target="_blank" href="http://blog.com/">Blog</a>
                <a href="events.html">Events</a>
                <a href="stores.html">Store Locations</a>
                <a href="ind.html">Site Map</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Customer Service</b>
                <a href="shipping.html">Shipping</a>
                <a href="returnpolicy.html">Returns</a>
                <a href="giftcert.html">Gift Certificates</a>
                <a href="privacypolicy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
                <a href="terms.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I expect to see:[image]

This is what I see:
[image]

Anyone have any insight to why the doctype does not set the td on their own line?  I am using Chrome.  I checked firefox and it works as expected.

Comment: Well, the HTML doctype you're using is not valid, so this will trigger quirks mode. If you can't use a proper doctype, and you can't change the content to use divs, I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: Oh, if you're wondering why Firefox behaves correctly, that's no great mystery. Just a matter of different browsers having different quirks. This is exactly the reason why you should avoid quirks mode whenever possible.

Comment: Say, on re-reading the question, are you saying that the CMS has the possibility to emit an XHTML doctype?

Comment: @MrLister thanks for you comments.  Yes, the doctype is coded in the closed source of the CMS.  I did find the ability to enable the loose definition "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> I did find the ability to enable the loose definition "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"; which solved the issue.

**References**

- [Doctypes and markup styles - Web Education Community Group](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Doctypes_and_markup_styles)